# Add CRL to CertPathValidator

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

How can I easily attach revoked certificates to a certificate validation via `CertPathValidator`?

This is my current code:

```
public boolean validateCertificate(X509Certificate certificate) {
    try {
        // Create trust anchor from current CA X509Certificate
        TrustAnchor trustAnchor = new TrustAnchor(this.getCACertificate(), null);

        // This is the certificate which should be validated
        CertPath cp = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertPath(Collections.singletonList(certificate));
        CertPathValidator cpv = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");

        // TODO: Add the list with the revoked certificates 
        List<X509Certificate> crl = new ArrayList<>();

        PKIXParameters pkixParams = new PKIXParameters(Collections.singleton(trustAnchor));
        pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);

        CertPathValidatorResult result = cpv.validate(cp, pkixParams);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I read a lot but I have not found any easily solution, because I am currently not using a `KeyStore` or `CertStore`.

Thanks in advance!